# Rails validates failed with a simple validation

Tags: validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I need validate the 'name' attribute of B class only when the attribute 'need_name' of A class is true. But I have a trouble with this validations.

My code:

```
class A
    validates :need_name, presence: true
end

class B
    validates :name, :presence => :need_name?

    belongs_to :a

    def need_name?
        A.find(a).need_name
    end
end
```

And my tests:

```
describe A do
    context "validations" do
        it { should validate_presence_of :need_name }
    end
end

describe B do
    context "validations" do
        it { should validate_presence_of :name }
    end
end
```

The test of class A works fine but I received this erro when I run the test of B class:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:Validation failed: Need name can't be blank
```

The error disappears if I set true to the 'need_name' and I can't understand why this happens.

I really appreciate any help. Thank you guys.

Comment: What's `a` in `A.find(a).need_name` ?

Comment: @KirtiThorat the association with B class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the way the validation is done to:

```
class A
    validates :need_name, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
end

class B
    validates :name, :presence => { if: :need_name? }
    belongs_to :a

    def need_name?
        a.need_name unless a.blank?
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't validate class A from within class B.

I'd validate the presence of the relation from class B, and then use `validates_associated` ([described here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated)) to trigger validations on A.

```
class A
    validates :need_name, presence: true
end

class B
    belongs_to :a
    validates_presence_of :a
    validates_associated :a
end
```

In the above code instances of class B will only validate if there's an association with a class A instance present *and* if the associated instance passes validation (i.e. has `need_name` set).